# How can I access alternate labels in ANTLR4 while generically traversing a parse tree?

Tags: pretty-print, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

How can I access alternate labels in ANTLR4 while generically traversing a parse tree?  Or alternatively, is there any way of replicating the functionality of the `^` operator of ANTLR3, as that would do the trick.

I'm trying to write an AST pretty printer for any ANTLR4 grammar adhering to a simple methodology (like naming productions with alternate labels).  I'd like to be able to pretty print a term like `3 + 5` as `(int_expression (plus (int_literal 3) (int_literal 5)))`, or something similar, given a grammar like the following:

```
int_expression 
    : int_expression '+' int_expression # plus
    | int_expression '-' int_expression # minus
    | raw_int                           # int_literal
    ;
raw_int
    : Int
    ;
Int : [0-9]+ ;
```

I am unable to effectively give names to the `plus` and `minus` productions, because pulling them out into their own production causes the tool to complain that the rules are mutually left-recursive.  If I can't pull them out, how can I give these productions names?

Note 1: I was able to get rid of the `+` argument methodologically by putting "good" terminals (e.g., the `Int` above) in special productions (productions starting with a special prefix, like `raw_`).  Then I could print only those terminals whose parent productions are named "`raw_`..." and elide all others.  This worked great for getting rid of `+`, while keeping `3` and `5` in the output.  This could be done with a `!` in ANTLR3.

Note 2: I understand that I could write a specialized pretty printer or use actions for each production of a given language, but I'd like to use ANTLR4 to parse and generate ASTs for a variety of languages, and it seems like I should be able to write such a simple pretty printer generically.  Said another way, I only care about getting ASTs, and I'd rather not have to encumber each grammar with a tailored pretty printer just to get an AST.  Perhaps I should just go back to ANTLR3?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest implementing the pretty printer as a listener implementation with a nested visitor class to get the names of the various context objects.

```
private MyParser parser; // you'll have to assign this field
private StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

@Override
public void enterEveryRule(@NotNull ParserRuleContext ctx) {
    if (!builder.isEmpty()) {
        builder.append(' ');
    }

    builder.append('(');
}

@Override
public void visitTerminalNode(@NotNull TerminalNode node) {
    // TODO: print node text to builder
}

@Override
public void visitErrorNode(@NotNull TerminalNode node) {
    // TODO: print node text to builder
}

@Override
public void exitEveryRule(@NotNull ParserRuleContext ctx) {
    builder.append(')');
}

protected String getContextName(@NotNull ParserRuleContext ctx) {
    return new ContextNameVisitor().visit(ctx);
}

protected class ContextNameVisitor extends MyParserBaseVisitor<String> {
    @Override
    public String visitChildren() {
        return parser.getRuleNames()[ctx.getRuleIndex()];
    }

    @Override
    public String visitPlus(@NotNull PlusContext ctx) {
        return "plus";
    }

    @Override
    public String visitMinus(@NotNull MinusContext ctx) {
        return "minus";
    }

    @Override
    public String visitInt_literal(@NotNull MinusContext ctx) {
        return "int_literal";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a generic way to do this without writing a specialized pretty printer for each language.  Is there no way to do this?  From a user's perspective, I don't understand why there isn't, since the alternate labels are right there.

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't contain a method to access the alternate labels.

However there is a workaround. ANTLR4 uses the alternate labels to generate java class names and those java classes *can* be accessed at run time.

For example: to access alternate labels in ANTLR4 while generically traversing a parse tree (with a listener) you can use the following function:

```
// Return the embedded alternate label between
// "$" and "Context" from the class name
String getCtxName(ParserRuleContext ctx) {
    String str = ctx.getClass().getName();
    str = str.substring(str.indexOf("$")+1,str.lastIndexOf("Context"));
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    return str;
}
```

Example use:

```
@Override
public void exitEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) {
    System.out.println(getCtxName(ctx));
}
```